# Не сохраняются фото в телеграм

Tags: c#, telegram-bot, save, photo

Пытался найти способ сохранения, и самый частый:

```cs
await DownloadFile(msg.Photo[msg.Photo.Count() - 1].FileId, "photo" + ".jpg");


private static async void DownloadFile(string fileId, string path)
        {
            try
            {
                var file = await client.GetFileAsync(fileId);

                using (var saveImageStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    await file.FileStream.CopyToAsync(saveImageStream);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error downloading: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Но выдает ошибку (я подключил библиотеку `using System.IO`):

> Ошибка    CS1061  "File" не содержит определения "FileStream", и не удалось найти доступный метод расширения "FileStream", принимающий тип "File" в качестве первого аргумента (возможно, пропущена директива using или ссылка на сборку).

Comment: "file" и "client" - что за классы? Откуда код?

Comment: `private static string token { get; set; } = "1608743937:AAGGSRg5EgHqtXHtPF-eTu4KhdYX2xeKlvM";
private static TelegramBotClient client;`